# Nested AND function within a TEXTJOIN function is not returning results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

Given a U-Factor and SHGC, I need the corresponding Territory Codes to be concatenated and output in Cell B8.

For example, given a U-Factor of 0.3 and a SHGC of 0.25, the only territories that have a U-Factor <= 0.3 AND SHGC <= 0.25 are the SouthCentral and Southern territories. The output I desire is their corresponding Territory 
Codes, "SC" and "S", respectively. Thus, the final result should read, "SCS".

The formula that I have worked out is `TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(AND(C2:C5<=A8,D2:D5<=A9),A2:A5,""))`

Seems pretty straight-forward, but I am only getting the empty string as a result. See the image above for reference

To demonstrate the successful use of my function without the AND logic, I have included the TEXTJOIN results when applied to ONLY UFactor or SHGC in cells C8 and D8, respectively. It is only when combining these results using the AND function that it goes awry. The formula to obtain the contactenated results for only the UFactor output in Cell C8 is: `=TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(C2:C5<=A8,A2:A5,""))`

Note: Don't forget to use CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER else you will get an error, as this is an Array Formula. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND (or OR for that matter) do not play well with array formulas. Both AND and OR use a form of cyclic calculation by themselves that fouls up the cyclic calculation of an array formula. You need to nest IF statements instead.

```
' AND two conditions in an array formula
=TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, IF(C2:C5<=A8, IF(D2:D5<=A9, A2:A5, ""), ""))

' OR two conditions in an array formula
=TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, IF(C2:C5<=A8, A2:A5, IF(D2:D5<=A9, A2:A5, "")))
```

Finish with CSE.